# Rewrite Multiple Urls in Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have been trying a lot of combination to rewrite these three instance URLs

```
https://www.myjohara.com/jewelry?jwelurl=Rings
https://www.myjohara.com/collection?caturl=The-Global-Collection
https://www.myjohara.com/productdetails?purl=Pearl-Ball-Choker-Yellow-Gold
```

to either

```
https://www.myjohara.com/Rings.html
https://www.myjohara.com/The-Global-Collection.html
https://www.myjohara.com/Pearl-Ball-Choker-Yellow-Gold.html
```

or

```
https://www.myjohara.com/jewelry/Rings.html
https://www.myjohara.com/collection/The-Global-Collection.html
https://www.myjohara.com/productdetails/Pearl-Ball-Choker-Yellow-Gold.html
```

I have used this htaccess code which only works on the first condition i.e.
https://www.myjohara.com/jewelry/Rings.html

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /jewelry?jwelurl=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /collection?caturl=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /productdetails?purl=$1 [L]
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution if any one needs help on similar issues

```
RewriteRule ^collections/([^/]*)\.html$ /collection?caturl=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^jewelrytype/([^/]*)\.html$ /jewelry?jwelurl=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^products/([^/]*)\.html$ /productdetails?purl=$1 [L]
```

Sample Collection Link  - https://www.myjohara.com/collections/The-Global-Collection.html

Sample Jewelry Type Link - https://www.myjohara.com/jewelrytype/Rings.html

Sample Product Link - https://www.myjohara.com/products/The-Drop-Diamond-Ring-Yellow-Gold.html